# zeromq failing after running for a bit

Tags: python, rest, zeromq, hypercorn

I currently run a process as well as an API. These two need to communicate, more specifically the API to the process. For this I am using zeromq's python library. My code is as follows:

`server.py`:

```py
from zmq import POLLIN, ROUTER
from zmq.asyncio import Context, Poller
from zmq.auth.asyncio import AsyncioAuthenticator

    async def start(self):
        """Starts the zmq server asyncronously and handles incoming requests"""
        context = Context()

        auth = AsyncioAuthenticator(context)
        auth.start()
        auth.configure_plain(domain="*", passwords={"user": IPC_TOKEN})
        auth.allow("127.0.0.1")

        socket = context.socket(ROUTER)
        socket.plain_server = True
        socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

        poller = Poller()
        poller.register(socket, POLLIN)

        while True:
            socks = dict(await poller.poll())

            if socket in socks and socks[socket] == POLLIN:
                message = await socket.recv_multipart()
                identity, request = message
                decoded = loads(request.decode())
                res = await getattr(self, decoded["route"])(decoded["data"])
                if res:
                    await socket.send_multipart([identity, dumps(res).encode()])
                else:
                    await socket.send_multipart([identity, b'{"status":"ok"}'])
```

`client.py`:

```py
from zmq import DEALER, POLLIN
from zmq.asyncio import Context, Poller

async def make_request(route: str, data: dict) -> dict:
    context = Context.instance()
    socket = context.socket(DEALER)
    socket.identity = uuid.uuid4().hex.encode('utf-8')
    socket.plain_username = b"user"
    socket.plain_password = IPC_TOKEN.encode("UTF-8")
    socket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")

    request = json.dumps({"route": route, "data": data}).encode('utf-8')
    socket.send(request)

    poller = Poller()
    poller.register(socket, POLLIN)

    while True:
        events = dict(await poller.poll())
        if socket in events and events[socket] == POLLIN:
            multipart = json.loads((await socket.recv_multipart())[0].decode())
            socket.close()
            context.term()
            return multipart
```

This works perfectly fine for the first few requests but after a certain number of requests this code fails silently (without error) and I get no IPC responses. When I curl the API that uses this code as a client to my second process the request times out. [image: Timeout]

I assume this is because the processes are not properly closed or clogged up but I am not sure how to fix this. Here I ran an lsof command on my server after this code ran for a bit and stopped working: [image: lsof output]

How can I prevent these connections from timing out after a while?

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @D.L I've added the imports (except the IPC_TOKEN constant I hope that is self explanatory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out this is not a zeromq issue. I requested the zeromq TCP endpoint when the API started failing and it still returned data just fine. It is instead an issue with hypercorn which I have yet to figure out. Hard to spot where an issue is coming from when you have a lot of moving parts! I hope this at least helps someone else with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

With the `ROUTER` socket, there is an empty frame between the identity and the actual message: https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter3/#ROUTER-Broker-and-REQ-Workers

Not sure why it would even work in the first few attempts, but I think you need to change your code to do the following:

```
identity, empty, request = message
...
if res:
    await socket.send_multipart([identity, b'', dumps(res).encode()])
else:
    await socket.send_multipart([identity, b'', b'{"status":"ok"}'])
```

Comment: Hi Matteo, thanks for your help! It is really weird, I just tested it and it errors with two many values to unpack. However your answer would explain how it silently fails at some point, eg the request is still sent, just with an empty frame. So I have now have it try to unpack message into 3 variables and if that is not working into 2. Hopefully this fixes the issue. I will test it for a bit and then come back to let you know if this worked!

Comment: Sadly this did not work. The code is again failing just after a day without error.